# File Compression best practice when sending from client to server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, amazon-s3

I have multiple clients like web, mobile web, Android & iOS app as well. Now user is adding some information and along with that also uploading some files.

Now let's say my server is the one which will be responsible to upload files to amazon S3 and on success storing the meta data to DB. Now there is a possibility, client will upload multiple files along with some product information which also needs to be stored as data in DB.. So what should be the better approach to make rest call. Product information rest call and files upload rest call should be different? As User can upload multiple files at once so if we should be making a rest call to backend then is it good to send all those files to backend at once or what would be the better approach, considering mobile apps and mobile web as client as they might have slow internet connection plus too much of network overhead.

Please suggest a better approach to handle such scenario.

**Note:** It is a SpringBoot application but not in microservice style.